# Having several SQLiteOpenhelper in one appli Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to know if it is possible to have several DbOpenHelper in the same app Android but to use them to write and read in the same database?
because I'm trying to create tables from 2 different OpenHelper (with different names) and only the first one seems to create. when I try to run the 2nd one, i get an error...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like You can't have more than one helper for each DB. Here's explained why: http://blog.foxxtrot.net/2009/01/a-sqliteopenhelper-is-not-a-sqlitetablehelper.html

Comment: Indeed, that answers my question, I will have to merge my OpenHelpers and create my tables all at the beginning of my App.
thx matekm

Answer (score 1):

Add the `TABLE_CREATE` statement to `onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db)` to ensure that the second table gets created in case the database connection is already opened. Further, the `TABLE_CREATE` statement should include `IF NOT EXIST` in case the table already exists.

Reference: http://jiahaoliuliu.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/sqlite-create-multiple-tables-with-different-sqliteopenhelper-in-the-same-database/