# No such table in Android SQLite application with 2 tables

Tags: java, android, sqlite

There is the following code for saving Menu and Item objects:

```
public void setMenus(List<Menu> menus) {
    mMenuDataSource.saveMenus(menus);

    for (Menu menu:menus) {
        mItemDataSource.saveItems(menu.getItems(), menu.getId());
    }
}
```

MenuDataSource class:

```
public class MenuDataSource {
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private MenuSQLiteHelper mHelper;
    private String[] mAllColumns = { MenuSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            MenuSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, MenuSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_IS_ENABLED };

    private ItemDataSource mItemDataSource;

    public MenuDataSource(Context context) {
        mHelper = new MenuSQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void saveMenus(List<Menu> menus) {
        mDatabase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        for (Menu menu : menus) {
            long menuId = mDatabase.insert(MenuSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null,
                menuToContentValues(menu));
            menu.setId(menuId);
        }
    }

    private ContentValues menuToContentValues(Menu menu) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MenuSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, menu.getName());
        values.put(MenuSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_IS_ENABLED, menu.isEnabled());

        return values;
    }
}
```

ItemDataSource:

```
public class ItemDataSource {
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private ItemSQLiteHelper mHelper;
    private String[] mAllColumns = { ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_IS_ENABLED,
            ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COST, ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMPOSITION,
            ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COOKING_TIME, ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MENU_ID,
            ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMPOSITION };

    public ItemDataSource(Context context) {
        mHelper = new ItemSQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void saveItems(List<Item> items, long menuId) {
        mDatabase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        for (Item item : items) {
            long itemId = mDatabase.insert(ItemSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, itemToContentValues(item, menuId));
            Log.e("item_id", String.valueOf(itemId));
        }

        mDatabase.close();
    }

    private ContentValues itemToContentValues(Item item, long menuId) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, item.getName());
        values.put(ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, item.getDescription());
        values.put(ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMPOSITION, item.getComposition());
        values.put(ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COST, item.getCost());
        values.put(ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_IS_ENABLED, item.isEnabled());
        values.put(ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COOKING_TIME, item.getCookingTime());
        values.put(ItemSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MENU_ID, menuId);

        return values;
    }
```

}

MenuSQLiteHelper class:

```
public class MenuSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "menus";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_IS_ENABLED = "is_enabled";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " text, " +
            COLUMN_IS_ENABLED + " integer);";

    public MenuSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DbConstants.DATABASE_NAME, null, DbConstants.DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        Log.e("menu", "created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.e("menu", "updated");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

ItemSQLiteHelper class:

```
public class ItemSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "items";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String COLUMN_COMPOSITION = "composition";
    public static final String COLUMN_COST = "cost";
    public static final String COLUMN_COOKING_TIME = "cooking_time";
    public static final String COLUMN_MENU_ID = "menu_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_IS_ENABLED = "is_enabled";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " +
            TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " text, " +
            COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text, " +
            COLUMN_COMPOSITION + " text, " +
            COLUMN_COST + " integer, " +
            COLUMN_COOKING_TIME + " integer, " +
            COLUMN_MENU_ID + " integer, " +
            COLUMN_IS_ENABLED + " integer);";

    public ItemSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DbConstants.DATABASE_NAME, null, DbConstants.DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        Log.e("item", "created");
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.e("item", "updated");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code is very simple - it just creates 2 tables and save menu and items. But I get the following error: 
`"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: items: , while compiling: INSERT INTO items(composition,menu_id,cooking_time,is_enabled,cost,description,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"`

But if I save items without menu then all is good. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Can't guarantee it's part of the problem, but it seems like you aren't closing the DB when you finish your work in `saveMenus` (unlike `saveItems`, where you do close the DB).

Comment: Can you confirm that you have one database with two tables in it? Run the app on an emulator, then use the `adb shell` command in a terminal/command prompt to shell into the emulator. You can find the databases files in `/data/data/<your.package.name>/databases/`. Then you can use `sqlite3 <database_name>` to open the database and use `.tables` to see what tables are in it.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245054/3148941), and you'll find that you just can't have two SQLiteOpenHelper classes pointing at the same DB.

You could just split them into two different databases (by giving them different DB names), but what you probably want to do is merge the two SQLiteOpenHelper classes into one (so you can later run queries that use both tables).

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning there is no file of database.
When you run the methods of `mMenuDataSource` first, it's "oncreate" happens and it creates the database with the table "menus";
Then you run the methods of `mItemDataSource`, but the file of database is already created, so it's "oncreate" doesn't happend so nothing creates the "items" table.

You should create both tables in the same "oncreate" method.